Proving that a 2D function has multiple roots
I'm looking to extend one result regarding a one-dimensional exponential function to the two-dimensional case.
The problem in question is proving that $$x=f(x)=1-e^{-ax}$$ with $a>0$ has more than solution, or more precisely, that it has at least one non-zero solution, $x^*\neq 0$. This, of course, is a simplification of my problem, combining all the parameters into a single one, $a$.
In the following simplified case,

as $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0\ \ \forall x$, then if $f'(0)$ is not greater than $1$, $f(x)$ will never be able to reach the line $g(x)=x$. We can then conclude that $f'(0)\geq 1$. In this example, this means that if $a\geq 1$, there will be a solution $x^*\neq0$.
Now, what I am trying to do is extend this to two dimensions. I arrived at two possible formulations, and finding an answer for any of the two would be fine. With $a>0$ and $b>0$, these are:
1 - Having one equation combining $x$ and $y$, which lead me to $$a\,x+b\,y = a+b-(a+b)e^{-ax-by}.$$
Here is an example plot:

2- Having two equations, one for each variable, leading to
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x = 1-e^{-ax-by}\\
y = 1-e^{-ax-by}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
In both cases, $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is always a solution. But as before, what I want is to find some condition that ensures that a solution $(x^*,y^*)\neq(0,0)$ to the equation(s) exists. Ideally, this condition should be analogous to the one found in the one-dimensional case, $f'(0)>1$, but how can this be extended to two dimensions?
As a side note, in the second formulation, if we rewrite the equations as $
\left(\begin{matrix}
x\\y
\end{matrix}\right)=\vec F(x,y)$, then the condition that I would have expected to find (based on what the parameters mean on my problem) can be written as $\mathrm{Tr}[DF(0,0)]\geq1$, but I'm not sure that this is correct, or how could I prove it if it was.

In the second formulation of the larger problem, consider the restriction to the line $x = y$. Then proving the existence of a second solution to
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x = 1-e^{-ax-by}\\
y = 1-e^{-ax-by}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
becomes the same as proving there's a second solution to
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x = 1-e^{-ax-bx}\\
x = 1-e^{-ax-bx}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
which is really just
$$
x = 1-e^{-(a+b)x}
$$
which is the 1D problem for which you already have a solution! (because $a, b > 0$ ensures $(a+b) > 0$).
In short: in the second formulation, not only is there always another solution, but there's one along the line $x = y$.
Post-comment addition
I'm beginning to suspect you mis-formulated the problem, but let's assume not. The second formulation says this:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x = 1-e^{-ax-by}\\
y = 1-e^{-ax-by}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
The right hand sides of those two equations are equal, so if $(x, y)$ is a solution, then the left-hand sides must also be equal, i.e., we must have $ x = y $.
So we can actually conclude that (1) there's a solution to those equations on the line $x = y$, as shown above, and (2) any solution of those equations must lie on the line $x = y$.
If we look at the graphs of $y_1 = x$ and $y_2 = 1 - e^{-ax}$ (where $a > 0$) and do a tiny bit of calculus, it's clear that for $a > 1$, there are exactly two solutions to $y_1 = y_2$, one of which is at $x = 0$. The same is true for $1 > a > 0$; the only difference is that the second solution has $x < 0$. But at the special value $a = 1$, the "two" roots are in fact both at $x = 0$, so in your initial discussion, where you say:

The problem in question is proving that $$x=f(x)=1-e^{-ax}$$ with
$a>0$ has more than solution, or more precisely, that it has at least
one non-zero solution, $x^*\neq 0$.

it's clear (from the case $a = 1$) that you cannot prove this statement, because it's not true.
I think that this pretty much closes out the whole analysis.

Thank you for your response! That might be the answer i sought. However, I don't know for sure, because there could be a solution outside the line $x=y$. Thus, the condition to find a solution on the curve $x=y$ might be sufficent but not necessary to guarantee the existence of a non-zero solution.

Your question said "what I want is to find some condition that ensures that a solution (∗,∗)≠(0,0)
to the equation(s) exists"; I've shown that not only does a solution exist, but that there's a solution on the line $x = y$. So I've definitely answered your question! Is the solution unique? Almost certainly not...but that isn't what you asked!

See post-comment additions to my answer.
